# How can I assign a private mutableStateOf to a State variable in Android Jetpack?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I hope to set `_isRecording` inside `SoundViewModel` class, and I hope to expose `isRecording` to UI.

But the Code A is wrong, how can I fix it?

**Code A**

```
    class SoundViewModel @Inject constructor(): ViewModel() {
    
        private var _isRecording by mutableStateOf(false)
        val isRecording: State<Boolean> by _isRecording  //It's wrong
        //val isRecording: State<Boolean> = _isRecording  //It's wrong
        ..
    }
```

**Add content:**

To nglauber: Thanks!

I think Code B will work well.

Which is better between your code and Code B?

**Code B**

```
class SoundViewModel @Inject constructor(): ViewModel() {

   var isRecording by mutableStateOf(false)
              private set

}


@Composable
fun YourComposable(soundViewModel: SoundViewModel) {
   //I can use soundViewModel.isRecording directly
}
```

Comment: Code B is the correct solution in this scope. So you can use it with your Compose app safely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CLEARLY -- Code B is the best option. That's exactly what official Compose Docs recommend. The method with the underscore was adopted for `LiveData` objects, but when you shift to the Compose-compatible `MutableState<T>`, it is simply de-efficiencizing(?) your code, if you add that extra underscore step.

Check out the [State-in-Compose](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-statw) for full insights.

Go with the simplest approach that gets the job done, always the rule of thumb.

Comment: The link is dead. Instead, use https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state

Answer (score 3):

When you use the keyword `by`, it's basically an alias to `getValue`/`setValue`. Therefore:

```kotlin
// _isRecording is a Boolean
private var _isRecording by mutableStateOf(false)
// _isRecording is a State<Boolean>
private var _isRecording = mutableStateOf(false)
```

This is why you're getting this error.

You should expose like this:

```kotlin
class SoundViewModel @Inject constructor(): ViewModel() {

    private var _isRecording = mutableStateOf(false)
    val isRecording: State<Boolean> = _isRecording
}
```

and consume like this:

```
@Composable
fun YourComposable(soundViewModel: SoundViewModel) {
    val isRecording by soundViewModel.isRecording
```

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: In general, I don't like the approach B because you're allowing this value to changed from anywhere. This violates the principle of encapsulation. For instance: imagine you need some validation before change this field and it is being changes from several different places... It wouldn't a good idea have to add this validation everywhere... I would prefer to keep it internally and define a setter to change its value.

Comment: Thanks! But the `var isRecording` in Code B is marked as  `private set`, so you can't change it from anywhere, and you can only change it inside the class `SoundViewModel`.

Comment: Oh! Yeah... You're right. I missed that 